# Is there a tensorflow op equivalent to a timer to measure elasped time?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to implement decays that are a function of elapsed time rather than number of steps. Is there a tensorflow operation similar to a timer that would allow me to do this?

I can of course simply feed the output of `time()` to the graph but having a graph op for this would be slightly more satisfying since I currently don't use any feed dict and would rather not just to have this operation.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I doubt there's a built-in for this.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq because I find it more fair to compare models based on a fixed amount of processing time on a given hardware, and more convenient to be able to schedule the time taken by my trainings. These are of course practical considerations, not academic ones.